# How can I record Vim encryption operation?

Tags: vim

I'm working with VIM and writing some plugins for IT
I use vim every day, but I have now a necessity to encrypt my files.
I liked the :X encryption with blowfish2 in Vim
But I need to encrypt and decrypt my files every time.
How can I record or map this encryption? because I'm using the same password for every file.
So I need some king of solution that I could type the password only one time and re-use.

I've tried

```
:norm qa
:X
:norm q
```

And

```
:w! /home/carlos/Downloads/teste.txt
    :norm @a
```

And hundreds of silly things :D
But I only got headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:X` sets a value of a (buffer) local option. All you need to do is to set the option globally. That is, use `set key=password` instead. Note that Vim will not save the password in the command history, so it's almost safe to use this. There are a couple of points though.

1. As it's a global option, it could influence some files you don't want to be encrypted. Use `setlocal key=` to prevent such files from being encrypted.
2. The input of `set` is echoed on the screen, so watch your back ;-) Also, you will not be prompted twice, so try not to make mistakes.
3. Do not put `set key=password` in your vimrc, unless you're absolutely sure no one else can read it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably coming at the problem from the wrong angle. I don't think Vim is the solution here but an encrypted filesystem you mount and unmount at will.

[EncFS](https://github.com/vgough/encfs) comes to mind, which is a FUSE-based filesystem but potentially unsafe. There's [Cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/) and dozens of others, it all depends on your OS, environment and safety requirements.

This also obviates the need to cache the password somewhere for repeated use.